# Python text file processing to simplify/remove terms in SQL files

Tags: python, oracle

**What is the best way to process a structured text file in Python to remove unwanted terms (that may span multiple lines, could have nested brackets etc.)?**

*Background:* In this case I'm trying to restore an Oracle SQL DDL file to the free Oracle Express Edition.

The `CREATE TABLE` statements include terms like `TABLESPACE meta_index` that reference tablespaces that do not exist. This leads to the tables not being created - which then causes even more errors when those tables are referenced later on to create indexes or foreign keys.

Removing the `TABLESPACE` terms causes the default tablespace to be used - which is perfect.

```sql
CREATE TABLE address
    (address_id                     NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL,
    address_text_1                 VARCHAR2(70 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    address_text_2                 VARCHAR2(70 BYTE),
    address_text_3                 VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    address_text_4                 VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    address_town                   VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
    address_county                 VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    address_country                VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    post_code                      VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)
  ,
  CONSTRAINT PKADDRESS
  PRIMARY KEY (address_id)
  USING INDEX
  PCTFREE     10
  INITRANS    2
  MAXTRANS    255
    _
     (
         
            
      
      
  ) )
  SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE     20
  INITRANS    1
  MAXTRANS    255
    _
     (
         
            
      
      
  )
  NOCACHE
  MONITORING
  NOPARALLEL
  LOGGING
/
```

The above example can be imported if I manually simplify it as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE address
    (address_id                     NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL,
    address_text_1                 VARCHAR2(70 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    address_text_2                 VARCHAR2(70 BYTE),
    address_text_3                 VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    address_text_4                 VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    address_town                   VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
    address_county                 VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    address_country                VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    post_code                      VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)
  ,
  CONSTRAINT PKADDRESS
  PRIMARY KEY (address_id)
  USING INDEX
  );
```

In this case there is a closing bracket after the first `STORAGE` term that we need to keep: `STORAGE())`.

If this was a HTML or XML file I imagine I could use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Have you considered regexp?

Comment: @JasonChia - I think I'm likely to make a mistake with regex, but it's probably the route I'll end up taking if there's not a beautifulsoup-like solution that can parse arbitary code (in this case SQL) with awareness of brackets, braces etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` function in order to cut off the part before the keyword `TABLESPACE` within such a code

```py
import re
import os
import cx_Oracle as orc

dir_file = os.environ['USERPROFILE']+'\\Path\\to\\your\\file\\table_create.sql'

def extractDDL():
    try:
        user     = 'hr'
        password = 'hr'
        host     = '192.168.56.102'
        port     = '1521'
        dbname   = 'myOracleDB'

        con = orc.connect(user, password, dsn=host+':'+port+'/'+dbname)
        cur = con.cursor()

        i = 0
        st = ''
        with open(dir_file,'r') as f:
            for l in f:
                s1 = l.strip().split('TABLESPACE')            
                s2 = re.split(r'\s',s1[0])
                if s1[0] == '':
                    st += ')'
                    i += 1
                    print(st)
                    #cur.execute(st)                    
                    st = ''
                    i = 0                    
                elif s2[0] == 'CREATE' and s2[1] == 'TABLE':
                    i = 1

                if i == 1:
                    st += ''.join(s1[0]) + '\n'
                    
    except Exception as e:
        print('e : ',e)
        print('st : ',st)

extractDDL()
```

where uncomment the DDL execution statement(`cur.execute(st)`) whenever you feel the statement seems OK.